# Is my Array of Int* all Initialized to NULL?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

I'm a Java programmer struggling to understand C pointers and arrays.  (FULL DISCLOSURE:  I'm also a CS student, and yes, this question helps me with a programming assignment.)

I'm trying to create an array of int* pointers, then ensure that every pointer is NULL.  Later, this will come into play when I need to look up data in the array; whether there is a valid int or a NULL in a given spot will be important.

So allocating the space for the array is easy, but how to set all those pointers to NULL?  Here's my less-than-stellar attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define TABLESIZE   10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int* table = (int*) malloc(TABLESIZE * sizeof(int));

    // Initialize all *int pointers to NULL
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<TABLESIZE; i++){
        if((table+i)!=NULL){           // They may be NULL already?  I don't know...
            *(table+i) = NULL;         // This generates a warning:
                                       // "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"
        }
    }

    // Sanity check :  are all int* are NULL ?
    for(i=0; i<TABLESIZE; i++){
        printf("%d:  %p  %d ", i, (table+i), *(table+i));
        if((table+i) == NULL)
            printf("(NULL)");
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(table);
    return 1;
}
```

Output is:

```
$ ./a.exe
0:  0x6000103c0  0
1:  0x6000103c4  0
2:  0x6000103c8  0
3:  0x6000103cc  0
4:  0x6000103d0  0
5:  0x6000103d4  0
6:  0x6000103d8  0
7:  0x6000103dc  0
8:  0x6000103e0  0
9:  0x6000103e4  0

$
```

So I'll be flat-out honest...  I don't know what the above tells me.  I'm guessing that I've created a 1D array where all the values in the array are valid ints, all 0.

But this is problematic for later in my program.  When it comes time for my code to insert data into table[x], the code must be able to look at the array and know if another valid int was previously inserted in the same spot.  If it sees table[x] = 0, does it conclude a 0 was inserted into index x, or that the spot is available?

I liked the idea of using an array of pointers to ints because that would neatly solve this problem.  If my code saw:

- table[x] --> NULL    // This spot is empty and available
- table[x] -->   0     // This spot is occupied, can't insert here

But I don't think I'm coding what I want.

Any thought/advice/comments/criticism is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
-Pete

Comment: "array of `int *` pointers" - so `int **[]`? There is no array of any type of pointer in your code!

Comment: NULL is just a #define NULL 0 so there is no difference of table[x] -> NULL and table[x] --> 0

Comment: @merl: That is nonsense! Typically `NULL´ is `#define NULL ((void *)0)`. And for documentation purpose/readbility, using the macro is recommended. Also a _null pointer_ is not required to have a bit-representation of all-zero.

Comment: `table[x]` is not a pointer, but an `int`. So assigning it with NULL won't make sense.

Comment: What in the description of `malloc` did you not understand?

Comment: @merl `NULL` and 0 may be different: ex on a 64-bit compiler. It can have it's importance, for instance when using varargs functions, pushing `NULL` and trying to pop integer. NULL is defined as is: `#define NULL ((void *)0)` as Olaf says.

Comment: @Olaf When comparing an array of ints against 0 or NULL shouldn't make any difference. OP wants to differantiate by that though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Though this is only the half of the truth. `NULL` **can** be `#define NULL 0`. That's why I wrote "typically". The integer `0` in pointer-context is interpreted as a _null pointer constant_. That is some of the worst and most irritating legacies in C (and C++). It is not the same as the integer `0`.

Comment: @merl: With a modern compiler and warnings enabled, you will get a type missmatch warning comparing a `void *` and an `int`. Let alone the conversion between a pointer type and an integer is implementation defined and very well **will** make a diference/problem on many systems. It is absolutely unclear what OP **really needs**!

Comment: @Olaf you are right, all I am saying is that OP cannot **differentiate** ints by 0 and NULL.

Comment: Wow!   This is why I seriously love this site.  I've gotta learn these finer points of syntax, and comments like these really help illuminate things for me!  Thanks to everyone!  :)

Comment: This: `int* table = (int*) malloc(TABLESIZE * sizeof(int));` is more robustly written as `int *table = malloc(TABLESIZE * sizeof *table);`

Comment: @KeithThompson `sizeof *table` seem too ambiguous for people not used to this..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Ok, then `int *table = malloc(TABLESIZE * sizeof (*table));`. (Or people could *get* used to it, and remember than `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.)

Comment: The traditional comments for C/malloc questions: _don't cast the return of `malloc` & co_. It's considered bad practice, and can hide errors. Also: to initialize the memory to NULL, just use  `table = calloc(TABLESIZE, sizeof *table);` and be done with it.

Comment: @KeithThompson That is a weak argument in support of omitting parenthesis (or adding a space to show it isn't a function). It doesn't matter if it is a function or not when you're not talking about C standard  rules and its implementation.

Comment: @2501: How does it not matter? `sizeof` doesn't look like a function (its name is a keyword, not an identifier), and it doesn't act like a function (its argument is, in most cases, not evaluated).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Always using parentheses makes the usage consistent with using a type (one sometimes has to). I'm well aware it is an operator, but use the parens anyway.

Comment: @Olaf: There are two forms of expression involving `sizeof`. One takes an expression as an argument. The other takes a parenthesized type name. The form that takes a parenthesized type name is unusual as expressions go (the more recently added `_Alignof` follows the same pattern). In the form that takes an expression, `sizeof` acts very much like a unary operator, like `-`, `~`, or `*`. I prefer to be consistent with those forms. The problem I have with `sizeof (expr)` is that it makes it look too much like a function call, and it's important to remember that it isn't (same for `return`).

Comment: @Pete any chance you could accept an answer?

Comment: @KeithThompson: The type-variant semantically is not an expression. And I did already state I'm well aware `sizeof` (and `_Alignof`) is an operator. It also is clear the parens are part of the expression, not `sizeof`. Yet I prefer using it.

Comment: @Olaf: Not sure what you mean by that first sentence. `(int)` is not an expression, but `sizeof (int)` certainly is. As for the optional parentheses, I don't strongly object to them, but I'm very firmly opinionated about my mild preference against them.

Comment: No need to cast the result of `malloc()` & Friends in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int* table = malloc(TABLESIZE * sizeof(int));
```

Does not create an array of pointers, rather it creates a single `int` pointer to the start of block of allocated memory of size `(TABLESIZE * sizeof(int))`

The reason you are getting an error is that an `int*` is just that; a pointer to an `int`.

The `*` operator is called the 'dereference' operator. Its job when placed *before* a variable is to say 'go to wherever this pointer is pointing'. Therefore, the line

```
*(table+i) = NULL;
```

Means 'go to wherever table is pointing, move along `i * sizeof(int)`, then set that particular `int` to NULL. This obviously doesn't make sense - you can't set a an `int` to NULL, as that's a pointer value. Hence your error.

*By the way, since pointers can also be treated like arrays in C, the above line is also the exact equivalent of*

```
table[i] = NULL;
```

If you want your initial malloc to be an array of pointers you need to allocate space not for `int` but for `int*`, so you could do

```
int** table = malloc(TABLESIZE * sizeof(int*));
```

Then you have an `int**` (Double pointer - aka a pointer to a pointer) referencing a block of TABLESIZE `int*`'s

Once you have done this, the code below that line will correctly set your pointers to `NULL`. To then achieve the table as described in your question, you will need to do a further malloc for each cell before you put an `int` in it. So for example to put '3' into cell 2

```
if(*(table + 2) == NULL) {
   *(table + 2) = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
**(table + 2) = 3;
```

Note the double deference on the last line: 'Go to wherever `table` is pointing, move along `2 * sizeof(int*)`, then go to wherever *that* pointer is pointing.' Again, this can also be achieved with array syntax

```
if(table[2] == NULL) {
    table[2] = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
*table[2] = 3;
```

Be careful not to call `malloc()` on the same cell twice; if you do this you will have a memory leak.

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc` and friends, it's considered harmful. It's required in C++, but frowned upon in C

Comment: "... creates a single `int` pointer ..." - No. The `int` pointer is defined by `int *table`. `malloc` returns a(n untyped) memory block with the given number of bytes. It becomes an array of `int` by the first write through that pointer.

Comment: @Olaf Can you provide a source for that; your comment is contrary to how I understand pointers to work.

Comment: @BenWainwright: The pointer apparently exists without `malloc`ing an object and assiggning that address. My reference is the C standard. Always a good reading. And me knowing the C language. You confuse the object and **a** pointer to it.

Comment: @BenWainwright `int *table = NULL;` obviously "creates" a pointer pointing to `NULL` without any `malloc()`.

Comment: *By the way, since pointers can also be treated like arrays in C,* in this generic form it is at least misleading. The *access* to an object that is referred by a pointer *can be done as* the pointer would be declared as an array. That's all. There are big fundamental differences between arrays and pointers.

Comment: Do not confuse the OP, @AminNegm-Awad. int *table = NULL; does not produce a pointer to NULL -- it creates a variable of pointer type whose value, not its referrent, is NULL. I.e., a null pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The variable of pointer type *contains* a `NULL`-pointer. A `NULL`-pointer is a pointer by definition.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, yes, but a `NULL` pointer is not the same thing as a pointer ***to*** `NULL`.  By definition, a `NULL` pointer does not ever point to anything.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know that. But this does not make my answer invalid in any way.

Comment: @BenWainwright Thanks Ben, this is great.  Very clearly explained.  :)

Comment: For completeness: This`*table[2] = 3;` is equivalent to `table[2][0] = 3;`.

Comment: @alk While that is true, it is not going to be a helpful idiom in this case, because the asker is not intending to use these pointers as arrays, so to use array syntax to access them may confuse matters.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm a Java programmer struggling to understand C pointers and arrays.

Yes, the "struggling" part is evident in your code.

A C array is simply an ordered collection of elements of a specified type, arranged contiguously in memory.  This is similar to a Java array, but Java provides no means for you to see or probe the arrangement of the elements in memory, and its arrays have additional data associated with them (in particular, they know their own lengths).

A C pointer is a value that represents the address of some other object, where "object" means a stored value of any type, including built-in (Java: "primitive") types, aggregate types (structures and arrays), pointer types, and even no particular type.  This is similar in some ways to a Java "reference", which is reflected in the fact that Java raises "Null*Pointer*Exception" if it tries to dereference a null reference.

It is very important to understand that although there is a close relationship between arrays and pointers, *they are not at all the same thing*.  That should be clear from the descriptions above, but I regularly come across clueless claims to the contrary.

It is also important to understand that pointer values can be invalid -- not pointing to any object.  You can easily have a pointer value, maybe stored in a variable or an array, whose value is garbage.  This is something to *manage*, not to be afraid of.

Furthermore, it is important to understand that pointer values do not necessarily have to be obtained via memory allocation functions.  They can also be obtained via the address-of operator (`&`) or through evaluation of an expression involving an array, or garbage pointer values can spring up naturally when a pointer is declared but not initialized.

> I'm trying to create an array of int* pointers

I'm not sure whether you mean an array whose elements have type `int *` (pointer to int), an array whose elements have type `int **` (pointer to pointer to int), or maybe an array whose elements have type `int`.  My guess from your wording would be the first, reading you literally yields the second, and your actual code presents something like the third.

This would be the declaration of an array of `int *`:

```
int *table[TABLESIZE];
```

Not having specified an *initializer*, you cannot rely on any particular values for the elements until you assign values.  Code similar to what you presented could be used for that (less the NULL check, which has undefined behavior on account of the initial values being indeterminate, and anyway would provide no advantage whatever), but I'd be inclined to write it slightly differently:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) {
    table[i] = NULL;
}
```

At this point, the elements of your table are all initialized with the one pointer value that you can be ***certain*** does not point to any object.  You can check those pointer values, but you must not dereference them:

```
// Sanity check :  are all int* are NULL ?
for(int i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) {
    printf("%d:  %p  ", i, (void *) table[i]);
    if(table[i] == NULL)
        printf("(NULL)");
    printf("\n");
}
```

> I liked the idea of using an array of pointers to ints because that
>   would neatly solve this problem. If my code saw:
>
> ```
> table[x] --> NULL // This spot is empty and available
> table[x] --> 0 // This spot is occupied, can't insert here
> ```

That does not make sense, because `0` interpreted as a value of any pointer type is a null pointer constant.  However, having started by assigning all elements of the table to be NULL, if you intend to set elements to valid pointers when you assign them, then you *can* check for `NULL` to see whether a spot is available, since `NULL` is never a pointer to an object.

Do note, by the way, that if you declare `table` as a *bona fide* array, as above, then you do not need to free it.  You might, however, need to free some or all of the objects to which its *elements* point, depending on whether those objects were dynamically allocated, and on whether they have been or will be freed by other means.

Comment: Thanks John, this does make sense.  I'm learning (with some bruises) that C syntax is a lot trickier than I bargained for.  This goes a long way to cleaning things up.  :)

Answer (score 2):

In both C and Java, `int` holds an integer value.  There is no additional, distinguishable null state.  Usually, every possible bit-pattern for an `int` represents a distinct integer value, so it is not physically possible to store this extra state.

If you want to implement something that can be "either 'null' or any possible value in the range of `int`" then you will have to use additional storage for each array entry. (For example, you could maintain a parallel set of boolean flags indicating whether each entry is "active" or not).

An alternative solution would be to reserve one particular integer value to represent that that array entry should be considered "empty". This technique is called *sentinel value*.

---

In Java you can have an array of `Integer` , which is an array of references that may either be "null" or refer to an `int` stored elsewhere (the language manages the allocation behind the scenes). To simulate that memory layout in C 
the code would be:

```
// Allocate array and initialize all entries to NULL
int * array[ARRAYSIZE] = { NULL };

// Insert at position (repeatable)
if ( array[2] == NULL )
    array[2] = malloc( sizeof(int) );
*array[2] = 10;

// Use item
printf("%d\n", *array[2]);

// Remove from position
free( array[2] );
array[2] = NULL;
```

To avoid memory leaks you will need to remember to loop through and do the removal procedure before `array` goes out of scope. It would also be good to check for `malloc` failure and abort the program or take some other action.

Note that this technique would be considered unusual in C, and not space-efficient compared to the other available options.

Comment: Ah.  The second part of your answer presents a very plausible explanation for what the OP wants to do.  I've enough Java background to be a bit embarrassed that it did not occur to me.

Comment: @M.M This is awesome, thanks for taking the time to lay this out.  I've copied this into my notes.  :)

Comment: `int * array[ARRAYSIZE] = { NULL };` only initialises the 1st element to `NULL` all other elements are initialised to binary `0`s, which not necessarily needs to result in the array's elements carrying a  `NULL`. Although the C Standard states that `char * p = 0;`  and `char p = NULL` shall compare equal, `NULL` does not necessarily needs to be represented by  a  binary `0`. Deriving from this: `if ( array[2] == NULL )` may fail.

Comment: @alk no, it actually makes null pointers. See C11 6.7.9/21 and /10

Comment: @M.M:I stand corrected. I somehow missed 6.7.9/21 explicitly refers */10. Thanks for pointing me to this. I seem to have mixed this up with case of doing: `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);`